# Split function "the_tags" in 2 columns

Tags: tags, columns, split

I have the following function that returns the tags of the current post:

```
<?php the_tags( '<ul> <li>', '</ li> <li>', '</ li> </ ul>' ); ?>
```

Example:

[image]

Is there any way to split the result into 2 columns?

Would return something like this:

[image]

Any hint is welcome. Thank you friends!

Comment: you can also check out the multi columns in CSS3, but that might not cover all browsers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_the_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) instead of `the_tags` to grab an array of tags, and [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split it. You will then need to build a loop to display the tags.

```
$tags = get_the_tags(); 
if (!empty($tags)) {
  $tags = array_chunk($tags,ceil(count($tags)/2),true);
  foreach($tags as $v) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($v as $tag) {
      echo '<li><a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}
```

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tag_link

Comment: Perfect @s_ha_dum! Now we need to find a way to use CSS3 to position the first <ul> left.

Comment: All you should need to do is `float` the `<ul>`s.

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant, lol.

Comment: I thought I should just add float in a `<ul>`. But really worked (at least in Chrome).